# Fiddler4 cannot capture websocket requests from an android app

Tags: android, google-chrome, websocket, fiddler

I am trying to capture app requests with fiddler4.  http requests can be captured smoothly by  setting fiddler and andriod mobile.
As we know, fiddler4 have already supported websocket.I also find that Fiddler4 can capture websocket requests from  chrome browser(I use http://www.websocket.org/echo.html to test ).

But it can not capture any websocket request from my app.I have printed out all the sessions in log by adding "FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString(oSession.ToString());" into OnBeforeRequest.

I am using:
Fiddler Web Debugger (v4.5.1.2)
my android app websockt  java_websocket(http://java-websocket.org/)